# Работа с символьным массивом

Tags: c++, массивы

Я не прошу мне расписывать весь код задачи, которая дана ниже.
Меня интересует алгоритм выполнения программы, что такое вхождения и к каким функциям придется обращаться для выполнения задачи на `С++`

Дан символьный массив образованный из слов и разделенных  пробелами.  С использованием процедур и функций выполнить:

1. Удалить из каждого слова все предыдущие  вхождения  последней буквы.
2. Заменить все вхождения `pgf` на `rtyue`.
3. Проверить есть ли в слове с указанным номером гласные буквы.
4. Определить количество слов в которые входят буквы  '`а`'  или  '`о`'.
5. Выдать на печать сначала пятое, а затем третье слово.

Comment: Если вы не понимаете что такое вхождение и даже не понимаете каким образом это обрабатывать - очень сомневаюсь что вы реализуете это все если вам объяснят что это такое. Но чтобы кратко - вхождения это ... вхождение, т.е. из слова "абракадабра" нужно удалить все буквы а кроме последней - получится "бркдбра". А символьный массив - это строка, вот и работайте со строковыми функциями

Comment: По хорошему вам никакие функции не нужны. идете в цикле по буквам массива, по наличию пробелов определяете начало и окончание слова. когда слово выделено (вам известны позиции его начала и окончания) проводите необходимые операции, переписываете слово (побайтно, обычным присвоением) например в другой массив, за исключением букв совпадающих с последней и заменяя комбинации pgf на rtyue. Это если у вас вся строка из латинских букв, а вот если там есть другие символы и кодировка вроде UTF-8, то у вас будет еще масса развлечений с определением длины буквы (символа)

Answer (score 0):

инициализируйте обьект std::string  этой строкой, и будут у вас все инструменты для работы со строкой

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/222771)

Comment: спасибо,   в дальнейшем учту, что если неохота или нет времени для подробностей, то не буду отвечать никому

Comment: @ARHovsepyan без подробностей обычно отвечают в комментариях, но у вас пока мало рейтинга чтоб комментировать чужие вопросы